# Use a single method to return data with different types

Tags: c#, .net, function, methods

I'm using ValueAs methods for each type supported by XPathNavigator.

```
public string GetFromNodeAsString(string xpathOfNode)
{
    XPathNavigator nodeNav = ipFormNav.SelectSingleNode(xpathOfNode, nsManager);
    return nodeNav.Value;
}

public int GetFromNodeAsInt(string xpathOfNode)
{
    XPathNavigator nodeNav = ipFormNav.SelectSingleNode(xpathOfNode, nsManager);
    return nodeNav.ValueAsInt;
}

public DateTime GetFromNodeAsDateTime(string xpathOfNode)
{
    XPathNavigator nodeNav = ipFormNav.SelectSingleNode(xpathOfNode, nsManager);
    return nodeNav.ValueAsDateTime;
}
```

The two things changing are the return types and what gets returned.
What is the best way to combine these methods? Is there no better way? I've experimented with using dynamic return types and passing respective data types but it didn't come together.

Comment: Make a class that holds these data type and pass that back....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
public T GetFromNode<T>(string xpathOfNode)
{
    XPathNavigator nodeNav = ipFormNav.SelectSingleNode(xpathOfNode, nsManager);
    return (T)nodeNav.ValueAs(typeof(T));
}
```

Comment: Ah, just what I was going to suggest. @kKode, this is a [generic method](http://www.dotnetperls.com/generic-method).

Comment: Nice. I was looking for a method with overloaded generics (`GetFromNode<T>` with specific overloads for `GetFromNode<int>` and `GetFromNode<string>` etc) but couldn't get it to work... guess I've been doing too much C++ lately :(

Comment: The type arguments for the method cannot be inferred from usage. I understand the problem, but clueless.

Comment: Specify the type explicitly, for example: GetFromNode<string>("sommething");

Answer (score -1):

I would create a struct, called *NodeData*.

```cs
public struct NodeData
{
    public string value;
    public int valueInt;
    public DateTime date;

    public NodeData(string v, int i, DateTime d) 
    {
        value = v;
        valueInt = i;
        date = d;
    }
}
```

and then use the method:

```cs
public NodeData GetFromNodeAsString(string xpathOfNode)
{
    XPathNavigator nodeNav = ipFormNav.SelectSingleNode(xpathOfNode, nsManager);
    return new NodeData(nodeNav.Value, nodeNav.ValueAsInt, nodeNav.ValueAsDateTime);
}
```

Comment: That would create an exception if the value cannot be converted to any of the types.